# Threading sublists on list

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

Suppose I have a list of the form:

```
list = {a, b, {c, d}, f, {g, h}}
```

i.e. an element of the list could be another list. I want to 'thread' each element of the sublist, so for the above result I should obtain 4 lists:

```
{{a,b,c,f,g},{a,b,d,f,g},{a,b,c,f,h},{a,b,d,f,h}}
```

The list could have arbitrary size and the sublist are arbitrarily distributed. How can I do it?

NOTE: Originally I am trying to map expressions involving AND and OR into lists of the AND elements, e.g.

```
a && b && ( c || d ) && f && (g || h)
```

should be mapped to

```
{{a,b,c,f,g},{a,b,d,f,g},{a,b,c,f,h},{a,b,d,f,h}}
```

I concluded that substituting AND and OR by list was a good start, hence the above statement of the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Distribute[list, List]
```

giving

> {{a, b, c, f, g}, {a, b, c, f, h}, {a, b, d, f, g}, {a, b, d, f, h}}

Comment: +1 Also, `Distribute[a && b && (c || d) && f && (g || h), Or, And, List, List]` works directly upon the original boolean expression.

Answer (score 2):

Not as elegant as `Distribute`, but there is also `Tuples`:

```
Tuples[List /@ list /. {{x__}} :> {x}]
```

> {{a, b, c, f, g}, {a, b, c, f, h}, {a, b, d, f, g}, {a, b, d, f, h}}

and `Outer`:

```
Flatten[Outer[List, ## & @@ (List /@ list /. {{x__}} :> {x})], 4]
```

> {{a, b, c, f, g}, {a, b, c, f, h}, {a, b, d, f, g}, {a, b, d, f, h}}